# A-frame automatically entering in full screen mode oculus go

Tags: aframe

I am using A-frame for building a VR website. I wish to enter vr-mode without having to press the 'enter-vr' glasses on the oculus go more than once. For my application most of the html (including the a-scene) get reloaded (but the header/footer remain in place). For pc browsers this code works:

HTML:

```
<a-scene id="eqvrscene">
</a-scene>
<button id="enterVRButton" onclick="$('#eqvrscene')[0].enterVR();"> Enter VR </button>
```

JS:

```
$("#enterVRButton")[0].click();
```

but this does unfortunately nothing on the oculus go. Does anyone have a suggesting how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s not posible. The [WebVR API](https://immersive-web.github.io/webvr/spec/1.1/#dom-vrdisplay-requestpresent) does not allow to enter VR mode automatically. It requires a user gesture like a click that cannot be synthetized like your example does. The only exception is when a page enters VR mode after user gesture, new pages are granted permission to enter VR automatically after navigation. A-Frame already accounts for the scenario and no extra application code is necessary.

Firefox also grants permision to enter VR automatically on page reload. That’s why you might be seeing a different behavior on desktop. Your code is not necessary, A-Frame auto enters VR automatically already. This case is not covered in the Oculus Browser

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not be related, but you have a typo in your `<a-scene>` tag.

It's difficult to tell from your code, but are you sure your scene is loaded when you click the button?

Try first listening for the `loaded` event of the scene, and then setting up a listener for the button:

```
// Scene entity element
var scene = document.querySelector('a-scene');

// Button element
var enterVRButton = document.querySelector('#enterVRButton');


// Check if scene has loaded, otherwise set up listener for when it does.
if (scene.hasLoaded) {
  addButtonListener();
} else {
  scene.addEventListener('loaded', addButtonListener);
}

// Add our button click listener.
function addButtonListener() {
  enterVRButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    scene.enterVR();
  });
}
```

In A-Frame `master` branch, there is an API in place for adding a custom button for entering VR, so it may be released in `0.9.0`. See the `master` docs: https://aframe.io/docs/master/components/vr-mode-ui.html#specifying-a-custom-enter-vr-button

If you're trying to automate the `click` event, I don't believe this will work in many browsers, as a user interaction is required for `enterVR()`.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the typo, you're right that I require user interaction for enterVR. :-)